# About Android launcher's WorkSpace

Tags: android, workspace, launcher

'Breakout' in WorkSpace by launching the game using the launcher as a source Launcher2 to gameplay available in the Android launcher screen to wonder whether this development.

The key is also used as a target to 4.2 Launcher for Android 4.2 features using basic Launcher2 source destination, but rather to develop a custom home run to add functionality as above.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: you can develop widget.